# thread-safe random number generation with cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to cythonise something I did which involves random number generation inside a parallelised loop. I wanted to use `mtrand` but since it's Python code it can't work from a `nogil` block and for some reason `mtrand`'s .pyx isn't exposed for the rest of us to use.

I know I can use `rand` or any other C RNG (e.g. `gsl`); is there a more standard way?

Answer (score 3):

You have summed up the situation correctly. As of this writing, you can do one of three things:

- Modify NumPy to allow sharing the declarations in mtrand.pxd
- Use NumPy's random generators through their default interface (perhaps you could store all the random numbers in advance outside of the `nogil` block?)
- Use a random number generator written in C (or possibly C++ if you are having Cython generate C++ code).

Honestly, I'd probably do the last one. If you can use C++ 11, there are several good random number generators now included in the C++ standard library that you could use.

Comment: In practical terms #3 is the most realistic one. However I am puzzled as to why `mtrand` is not exposed. If I am using the full `scipy` stack, why should I use a different RNG?

Comment: That's a good question. There are a variety of Cython files included throughout the scipy stack that aren't exposed as public interfaces. The only reason I can see for it is that many of the interfaces weren't really meant to be publicly supported parts of numpy/scipy. On the other hand, I'd bet that more and more of these interfaces will be made public in the future. I just stumbled on some relevant discussion at the Cython users discussion board: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/9UGMi_b3tVo