# Populate a matrix in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, vectorization, joblib

I need routinely populate matrices `A[i,j]` by evaluation of a function between pairs of vectors, as computation of every `i,j`-pair is independent from each other I want to parallelize this

```
A = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            A[i,j] = function(X[i], X[j])
```

How this computation could be elegantly parallelized via `joblib` or other widely used library?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How this computation could be elegantly parallelized via `joblib` or other widely used library?"*

If using `joblib`, the main python interpreter will spawn other, GIL-lock independent copies of its own ( yes, huge memory-I/O to copy all python interpreter state, including all data-structures in O/S Windows, somewhat less horrible initial latency hit in linux-type O/S ), yet the worse is only to come - any "remote" modification of the spawned/distributed replicas of the original data have to somehow make it back to the main-python-process ( yes, huge memory-I/O + cache-(de)coherency hardware workloads (plus per-core L1-data cache-efficiency almost for sure devastated) ).

So this trick does not easily pay for its own add-on costs, unless the **`function()`** computation is indeed many times above the costs of process-instantiation + process-to-process data interchange ( SER/DES on the way "there" ( one can imagine a `pickle.dumps()` memory allocation + pickling-compression/decompression costs ) + SER/DES on the way "back" + the actual p2p-communication latencies (costs) to move the pickled-data elements ).

One might like more reads on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262503/3666197) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382#33065382) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636480/python-using-multiprocessing-is-much-slower-than-loop-for-optimisation-problem/64642275#64642275).

---

### Is There Any Better Way Forwards?

We all have had for sure heard about `numpy` and smart `numpy`-vectorised processing. Many thousands of man*years top level HPC experience were put into the `numpy` smart data-I/O vectorised processing.

So in most cases, if you try to redesign the `function( scalarA, scalarB )` returnins a single `scalarResult` to be stored into an externally 2D-looped `A[i,j]` into an in-place modifying `function( vectorX_data, matrixA_results )` and let the inner code thereof do both the `i,j`-looping over the actual `matrixA_results.shape[0]` and do the actual computing, the results may get astonishingly faster, if the `numpy`-code can harness the smart CPU-vector instructions, that pay less than `0.5 [ns]` L1_data access latency times compared to as much as 300 ~ 380 [ns] RAM access latency times ( if memory-I/O channel were free and permitting unenqueued data transfer from the slow & far RAM-memory, not mentioning even the somewhat latency-masked `10.000.000+ [ns]` access-costs for using the `numpy.memmap()`-file-based data proxy ).

If one has never visited the domain of `numpy`-tricks with smart-vectorised processing, do not hesitate to read as many as possible posts from a true master in this domain, guru [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3293881%20%5Bnumpy%5D) - all respect to them!

Comment: okay, you say that joblib is overkill in my situation and suggest the vectorized operations instead, moreover invite me to think!

Comment: but I want a quick example how to do that, also I emphasize that a function operates on pairs of vectors of numbers (or even matrices) and returns a single number,

thanks

Comment: Ok, feel free to re-read the vectorised code examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62249186/how-to-use-prange-in-cython/62262503#62262503 ( or more from the smart-vectorisation guru-of-the-gurus @Divakar ) - once you get the concept of vectorised ( [:]-vector, [:,?]-matrix or [:,?,?]-tensor oriented syntax tricks ) operations, your code will burst into numpy-available super-performance